# Cannot Convert Existing React Native to Expo: error with nativeVersion.major

Tags: react-native, expo

Just downloaded the newest version of Expo XDE(2.20.1) and trying to convert an existing react native project into it. I followed precisely these [steps](https://github.com/expo/xde#converting-an-existing-project-to-work-with-expo), and when opening the app in Expo client on a real device, I got an error saying:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nativeVersion.major')

The problem happens both on Android and iOS.

Seems expo has a strict requirement of react/react-native versions, but unfortunately, I cannot find the version requirement list.

My current dependencies (which are quite up-to-date) are:

`"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.49.3"`

So, does this error indeed came from version conflicts? And if so, how do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JS dependencies need to match the native code. With Expo SDK 21, which is based off of React Native 0.48, you can either use (recommended):

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-21.0.2.tar.gz",
```

or:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.48.4",
```

It's important you are careful with the versions when you update your dependencies. The upcoming React Native 0.49 (supported with Expo SDK 22) needs to use React 16.0.0-beta.5.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easiest to create a new Expo project from scratch, then copy over your components. I've done this several times myself, and it's far easier than fighting whatever edge condition has affected you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your iOS build (`./app/ios/build`) folder and re-build.